# webpack-dev-server : command not found

Tags: javascript, mongodb, webpack, mean-stack, webpack-dev-server

[Webpack-dev-server:command not found in webpack used all global and local installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY4d4.png)

```js
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}

Comment: You have not asked  question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given it's a local dependency, you cannot invoke it globally (unless there's a global version installed). A good way to solve this is to run webpack-dev-server through npm. Set up a npm script at **package.json** like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
}
```

After that you can use either `npm start` or `npm run start` to begin developing through webpack-dev-server. npm patches env temporarily so that this will work.

You can also execute webpack-dev-server through `npm bin` directory. That's where a local installation generates an entry point for the bin version. This gives you something like `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` depending on your platform.